# Calculate audio speaking time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using this code for audio listening . its working fine .I dont have any idea how to calculate total time for audio before the audio playing . 
how to calculate total time required to play audio for any string ?

```
-(void)configureAudio {
    self.string = @"How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present";
    self.utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:self.string];
    self.utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
    self.utterance.rate = (float) 0.25;

    //Load UI
    self.textLabel.text = self.string;

}

- (IBAction)startSpeaking:(id)sender {

    self.speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

    if ([self.speechSynthesizer isSpeaking]) {

        [self.speechSynthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryWord];


     } else {

        [self.speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:self.utterance];

    }    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to know beforehand how much time the speech will take.

Comment: But some application like 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/voice-dream-reader/id496177674?mt=8
calculating time before audio read . @RamyAlZuhouri

Comment: I don't know which one, but I think that most likely they're using another framework.